# MySQL UTF8 varchar column size

Tags: mysql, utf-8, varchar

MySQL documentation says that since 5.0, varchar lengths refer to character units, not bytes. However, I recently came across an issue where I was getting truncated data warnings when inserting values that should have fit into the varchar column it was designated.

I replicated this issue with a simple table in v5.1

```
mysql> show create table test\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
Table: test
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `string` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I then inserted multiple 10 characters values with differing amounts of UTF8 characters

```
mysql> insert into test (string) values 
    -> ('abcdefghij'),
    -> ('ãáéíçãáéíç'),
    -> ('ãáéíç67890'),
    -> ('éíç4567890'),
    -> ('íç34567890');
Query OK, 5 rows affected, 4 warnings (0.06 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 4

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                     |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'string' at row 2 |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'string' at row 3 |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'string' at row 4 |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'string' at row 5 |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------+

mysql> select * from test;
+------------+
| string     |
+------------+
| abcdefghij |
| ãáéíç |
| ãáéíç |
| éíç4567 |
| íç345678 |
+------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I think that this shows that the varchar size is still defined in bytes or at least, is not accurate in character units.

The question is, am I understanding the documentation correctly and is this a bug? Or am I misinterpreting the documentation?

Comment: Not that it helps you in the slightest but [on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/829b8/2), which claims to be 5.5.20, one doesn't suffer this issue.  Perhaps it was a bug that has since been fixed (I've searched, but haven't located a bug report).

Comment: Same issue exists in 5.5.19, so that may be the version it was fixed. A check of the release notes shows no mention of varchars or UTF8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's true that VARCHAR and CHAR sizes are considered in characters, not bytes.

I was able to recreate your issue when I set my connection character set to latin1 (single byte).

Ensure that you set your connection character set to UTF8 prior to running the insertion query with the following command:

```
SET NAMES utf8
```

If you don't do this, a two-byte UTF8 character will get sent as two single-byte characters.

You might consider changing your [default client character set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_client).

Comment: This was indeed the problem. I would have expected the resulting record to display incorrectly if incorrect character set was used.